# Unable to pass down returned value from now view to another

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui

I have a view that returns a value called 'idd' in the form of a string: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lnw00.png)

Now I have a view called ListView where there is a navigationLink that essentially needs that returned 'idd' value to be passed to this view called NoteView which is that navigationLink's destination. However I'm not able to pass that value down to NoteView. When I use:

```
self.idd = datamanager.addnote()
```

to define idd in Listview([desc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AnTwQ.png)), it just says that ListView has no member idd. I've been struggling with this for days now, I'd appreciate if someone could give me their two cents! Thanks a ton.

EDITS: Described the code much better

List View: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iQPGD.png)

Here is how addNote returns idd [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6X3I.png)

Here is how NoteView that accepts the idd value when it's supposed to be passed down from ListView Navigation Link [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFAph.png)

Here is List View that is supposed to take the idd value

```
struct ListView: View {

    @StateObject var dataManager = DataManager()
    @State var isPresented = false

    var body: some View {

        NavigationView {

            ZStack{
                
            List(dataManager.notes) { note in
                NavigationLink(destination: NoteView(newNote: note.content, idd: note.id)) {
                    EmptyView()
               
                    Text(note.content)}.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
                
            .frame(height: 0)
              

            .navigationTitle("Notes")
                
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button (action: {},
                                  label: {
                    
                    NavigationLink(destination: NoteView(newNote: "", idd: "") )
                                          
          {Image(systemName: "plus")}
                      .simultaneousGesture(TapGesture().onEnded{
                          dataManager.addNote()
                      })}
                     ))
                    .listStyle(.plain)
                    .buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())     
        }
```

Here is addNote()

```
class DataManager : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var notes: [Note] = []
    @Published var idd = ""

    func addNote()-> String{
        let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
        let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
        let db = Firestore.firestore()



        var ref: DocumentReference? = nil
        ref = db.collection("userslist").document(uid).collection("actualnotes").addDocument(data: ["content":"New Note"])

        {error in

        if let error = error{
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

            else {
                    print("Document added with ID: \(ref!.documentID)")
              }

        }

        
      let  idd = ref!.documentID
        
         return idd
   
    }
```

Comment: Please add enough code so we can understand better how this views are defined and interact with each other. It´s a mere suggestion but from the one screenshot you can see, that there is no value `idd` defined in your ListView.

Comment: Hi @burnsi, sorry about that. I just added the entire code screenshots with their description. Pleas let me know if I can provide more description. Thanks!

Comment: Please add them as formatted text and not as images.

Comment: @burnsi I see what you’re saying but as shown in one of the previous screenshots, ref!.documentID doesn’t really crash and it does indeed gets logged into the console. So we know that and idd is being generated. I just need to know how i would pass it to Note View.

Comment: On general, using links is a bad idea here on SO. Sometimes links break and if that happens, future readers will have no idea what the question is about. Please include relevant information as text in the question or in the case of Firestore, include a screen shot of the structure.See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Can you also clue us in to what part of that code isn't working?